# Terraform ssh into instance and create directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, terraform, devops

I've just started using Terraform and have been struggling quite a bit. At the moment I am able to spin up an ec2 instance with my main.tf script

```
provider "aws" {
access_key = ""
secret_key = ""
region = "eu-west-1"

}

resource "aws_instance" "example"{
ami = "ami-07683a44e80cd32c5"
instance_type = "t2.micro"



}
```

At the moment for testing and understanding terraform I want to make a simple directory on my ec2 instance. I usually do this by ssh into my instance with putty but would like to automate this. I have looked at many tutorials and none have seemed to work.

If anyone would be able to point me in the right direction on where to start with this. From what I understand I'll need to create some security groups too which I am able to do.

From what I have seen I will need to do something along the line of this:

```
   provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
            //Executing command to creating a file on the instance
            "echo 'Some data' > SomeData.txt",
        ]

        //Connection to be used by provisioner to perform remote executions
        connection {
            //Use public IP of the instance to connect to it.
            host          = "${aws_instance.ins1_ec2.public_ip}"
            type          = "ssh"
            user          = "ec2-user"
            private_key   = "${file("<<pem_file>>")}"
            timeout       = "1m"
            agent         = false
        }
    }
}
```

many of these examples and tutorials I follow fail to work. Currently on windows 10 if that matters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any error that you get while taking the above approach?

Comment: Also, while creating the machine, you can specify the key pair name that use to ssh with the `key_name` parameter

Comment: Is the instance linux?

Comment: @FacePalm has provided me with the right solution I was going about it completely wrong Using key_name parameter worked like a charm

Comment: Hi Jack, glad that you found it useful. Can you add an answer ( since you have a better context ) with more details so that it's helpful for the community in future? Thanks